# In Shopify liquid, using Blockshop theme, Product variant does not appear in cart instantly unless I refresh page

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify, liquid

In Shopify liquid, using Blockshop theme, Product variant does not appear in cart instantly unless I refresh the page. When the conditions are met, cart.total_price >= 80 free_gift is not yet in cart, free_gift must add instantaneously without refreshing the cart. Any idea what I'm missing?

```
{% assign free_gift = false %}

{% for item in cart.items %}
    {% if item.id == 44899989815589 %}
      {% assign free_gift = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}


{% if cart.total_price >= 80 and free_gift == false %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    let freeGiftData = {
        "quantity": 1,
        "id": 44899989815589
    };
    let cartData = {
        "items": [
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "id": 44899989815589
            }
        ]
    };
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/cart/add.js',
            data: freeGiftData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function () {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/cart/update.js',
                    data: cartData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function () {
                        window.SLIDECART_UPDATE();
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert(error.responseJSON['description']);
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.responseJSON['description']);
            }
        });
    }
    function getCookie(cname) {
        let name = cname + "=";
        let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            let c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }


</script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Oh I'm using a slidecart app, thus windows.SLIDECART_UPDATE()

Comment: I think you need to check the same with an app developer, how do we refresh or rebuild the side cart when adding to the cart happens without refreshing the page?